# Get my global key listener to stop controls from responding to event?

Tags: swing

I wanted to add a global key listener to my app, it works fine but the 0th control in my app (a combobox) still has input focus and also responds to keypresses:

```
KeyEventPostProcessor pp = new KeyEventPostProcessor() {
    public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
};

DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().
    addKeyEventPostProcessor(pp);
```

Is there something like a "preProcessKeyEvent()" method I can override, which would stop the child controls from getting to see the event if I don't want them to process it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to prevent dispatching KeyEvents:

```
KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
};
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
```

But you should usually not need to perform such things. With appropriate [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) you should be able to achieve most of required behaviours.